# Programmatically click button in browser console not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

I am trying to write a script that clicks on "Buy Now" button on a webpage. You may refer to [this](https://www.flipkart.com/oneklik-analog-gold-twin-bell-alarm-clock/p/itmeyj7mycymwnct?pid=TCKEYJ3XSFGXQHZP) link for reference. I have wrote this script:

```
document.querySelectorAll('._3S6yHr._1i2f2k button')[1].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

and this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('._3S6yHr._1i2f2k button')[1].click()
```

but none seems to work. How can I overcome this restriction? Any possible workarounds?

**PS: jQuery is not available on the page.**

Comment: Are you sure it's the second one you want? ([1] == second, [0] == first)

Comment: Yes [0] is a good point.

Comment: @ggdx Yes, the second one.